# How do I translate a partial expression of SQL functions to SQL::Abstract?

Tags: sql, perl, dbix-class

I have a query that I would like to run as a DBIC result instead of query string.

The query is this:

```
"SELECT posts.*, (((LOG10(SUM(points.point) + 1) * 287015) + 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(posts.create_time))) as total FROM posts left join points ON
post.post_id = points.post_id GROUP BY posts.post_id ORDER BY total DESC"
```

Since I got relationships set up, I think i can avoid left join part on the query (my relationships in schema Post.pm file have has_many relationship set up to points table, so I am guessing that will do a left join with vibe points.

What I have now is the following:

```
$resultset->search(
{},
{
 select => [({sum => points.point} + 1) * 287015],
 as => [ 'total' ],
 group_by [qw/ id /],
 order_by => { -desc => 'total' },
}
);
```

I am having a problem integrating the LOG10 and sum points with addition of 1 and multiplication of 287015.

Any help is appreciated, I know that whatever I have there as a result, is not the way to do it, but I tried something and it didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested because you didn't provide a schema and example data:

```
'+select' => [{
    \'(LOG10(SUM(points.point) + 1) * 287015) + UNIX_TIMESTAMP(me.create_time)'
    -as => 'total'
}],
join => 'points',
group_by => 'me.post_id',
order_by => { -desc => 'total' },
```

Comment: what solved the problem for me was using *'+select' => [qq{(LOG10(SUM(poins.point) + 1) * 287015) + UNIX_TIMESTAMP(me.create_time) AS total}],*

Comment: it's also weird that if there are no points in table, it returns total as undefined, is this supposed to happen? SUM might return 0 and log of 1 is 0, 0 times x is 0, but UNIX_TIMESTAMP should return nice long integer so the sorting can be done. Hmmm.

Comment: Note that setting the environment variable DBIC_TRACE=1 you'll see the generated and executed SQL queries on STDOUT.